# Is my remote server behind NAT?

Tags: ssh, nat

I have a few remote servers in various locations. How can I detect if they're behind NAT? Of course, I can connect to them via ssh, but is that 100% sufficient to tell that they're not behind NAT?

Answer (score 2):

NAT can be done for incoming requests and/or for outgoing requests depending on the setup requirements.

To verify whether your server is behind NAT or not, login via SSH and check the address assigned to the server and compare it with the address you used to connect to server. If they are the same, there is no NAT for incoming requests. Similarly, you can do for outgoing requests.

Comment: `Similarly, you can do for outgoing requests.` -- how?

Comment: @Korioma: Request some service from a remote server you have to and check logged IP address.

Comment: `ip addr show` called on a server shows several ip addresses and among them there's one I use to connect to that server via ssh. Therefore, there's no NAT, right?

Comment: @Korioma: That's right